# Custom navigationBar on moreNavigationController

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

Hot to customize navigation bar that appear on "More" tab in UITabBarController to have 2 px line (in different color) as bottom border?

I created subclass of the UINavigationBar that overrides drawrect: method with drawing of that line, and that works for first four tabs, except tabs that are under more navigation controller.

Any help?

[image: Custom Navigation bar]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

And dynamically set the class of the more view controller's navigation bar:

```
object_setClass(yourTabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar, 
                [YourNavigationBarSubClass class]);
```

Comment: tnx a lot ;) you're the best!

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna change the background image you can do it inserting a UIImageView in the default navigation bar

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar"]]];
```